# rails model relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, relation

I have User model and Feedback model and User model has user_type attribute.
Feedback model also has user_id attribute.I want to add user_type column to Feedback model the same as in User model.For instance after the migration it should be like that

```
User
id:123
user_type: "customer"

Feedback
id:56
user_id:123
user_type : "customer"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you are putting user_type in feedback table too. You can retrieve it from user_id by using rails association.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :feedback
end 

class Feedback < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

To retreive user_type from feedback object use `@feedback.user.user_type`

Comment: depending on requirement if user has many feedbacks then use has_many :feedback in User Model.

Comment: It would either have to be `has_many :feedbacks` or `has_one :feedback`, but not `belongs_to :feedback` because there is no `feedback_id` field in the 'users' table.